# Как сформировать Bitmap на основе содержимого Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, bitmap, wpf-canvas

У меня есть изображение в Canvas, мне надо его перевести в Bitmap. Везде написан один и тот же код, где при переводе используется PixelFormats.Pbgra32. Данный параметр мне очень мешает, т.к. из-за него все цветовые компоненты пикселя меняют своё значение и мой Bitmap получается не таким, каким он есть на самом деле. Как мне доставать Bitmap из Canvas, чтобы ни один пиксел при этом не был изменён?

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap GetBitmapFromCanvas(Canvas canvas)
{
    Transform transform = canvas.LayoutTransform;
    canvas.LayoutTransform = null;
    Size size = new Size(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
    canvas.Measure(size);
    canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
      new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)size.Width,
        (int)size.Height,
        96d,
        96d,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderBitmap.Render(canvas);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap result;
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        encoder.Save(outStream);
        result = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
    }
    canvas.LayoutTransform = transform;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1. Укажите тот же самый формат который в канвасе. 2. А вы действительно уверены что изображение в Canvas совпадает с изображением первоисточника? Да, а всётаки, откуда у вас изображение в Canvas?

Comment: Указывал PixelFormats.Bgra32 - выдаёт исключение, что RenderTargetBitmap такой формат не поддерживает, хотя этот формат и является требуемым.

Comment: Какая у вас задача изначально? Откуда берётся источник изображения? Может вам лучше конвертировать через GDIPlus?

Comment: Я в изображение ввёл стеганографией текст. После этого мне становится очень важным сохранение всех бит пикселов изображения. Потом оно у меня обновляется, т.е. Canvas.Background становится равным моему изображению. А теперь мне надо из Canvas обратно достать Bitmap, чтобы я мог его сохранить. А если конвертировать через GDI+, то как?

Comment: Что значит "теряются" (стают чёрными или белыми, или B-R компоненты меняются местами)? И зачем у вас использован альфа-канал? Текст на прозрачном фоне?  Может у вас альфа-канал не верно обрабатывается?

Comment: В моей стеганографии используются все компоненты пиксела (R,G,B,A). Альфа-канал мне важен, т.к. алгоритм расшифровки стеганографии требует наличия правильного альфа-канала (иначе неправильно расшифрует). И получается, что при переводе из Canvas в Bitmap происходит перекодировка всех цветовых компонент моих пикселей и соответственно вся информация теряется.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что Canvas хранит alpha-канал?

Comment: А зачем вам `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, если вы пользуетесь WPF? Почему не просто-напросто [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Да, и непонятно, почему вы берёте картинку из визуального элемента. Если ваше приложение делает стеганографию, то картинку вообще не нужно показывать пользователю. Ну или можно показывать, но это так, сбоку, а вы должны работать с картинкой отдельно, не «запихивая» ей в `Canvas` и пытаясь достать назад.

Comment: Как мне из BitmapImage достать один пиксел, а вернее отдельно R, отдельно B, отдельно G, отдельно А ?

Comment: Кстати, насчёт того, что картинку не надо показывать пользователю, вы правы. У меня сразу после стеганографии идёт сохранение картинки с Canvas'а. А картинку я беру из визуального элемента, т.к. я на своём Canvas'e могу рисовать различные фигуры и сохранить мне желательно изображение со всеми нарисованными элементами.

Comment: разобрались с проблемой?

Comment: Нет, но нашёл способ её обойти